# SharePoint Online - Unshare

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing

Within SharePoint Online users with contribute or edit access can share a document/folder at will.  However, it appears that these same users can not "unshare" the same document/folder.

Users with full control access can remove share access, but I can not find a way for contribute or edit access users to do the same.

Is there a way for users with contribute or edit access to unshare documents/folders?

Comment: Is there an answer for this?  I just shared the wrong folder that way and I can't figure out how to unshare it!  Help, somebody!

Comment: I have no official answer yet.  However, it appears that the users must have access at the top level of the document library for this to work properly.